# Get Linux System Last Boot Time

Tags: php, linux, centos

From a PHP script I need to get the last system boot time, preferably in the UNIX time stamp format.

Are there any files that are created or modified at boot time? I could read the modified time of the file.

The system type is CentOS.

Comment: Standard unix way would be `who -r`, (or `who -b`) which reports the last change in runlevel, as stored in wtmp/utmp. But maybe that is too oldfashioned.

Comment: @wildplasser, thanks for that, as they say, you learn something new every day.

Comment: I am not sure about `who -b`. Could be a linuxism, just like the /proc/* thingy.

Comment: @wildplasser `-b` is available on SunOS but **not** FreeBSD at least.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

/proc/uptime

This file contains two numbers: the uptime of the system (seconds), and the amount of time spent in idle process (seconds).

```
<?php

function get_boottime() {
    $tmp = explode(' ', file_get_contents('/proc/uptime'));

    return time() - intval($tmp[0]);
}

echo get_boottime() . "\n";
```

Comment: Should add that simply subtracting the uptime from `time()` will give you the boot time as a unix timestamp. (May need to round/floor the value though - as /proc/uptime can contain decimals)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

**Method 1**

```
<?php
$uptime = trim( shell_exec( 'uptime' ) );
// output is 04:47:32 up 187 days,  5:03,  1 user,  load average: 0.55, 0.55, 0.54

$uptime = explode( ',', $uptime );
$uptime = explode( ' ', $uptime[0] );

$uptime = $uptime[2] . ' ' . $uptime[3]; // 187 days
?>
```

**Method 2**

```
<?php
$uptime = trim( file_get_contents( '/proc/uptime' ) );
$uptime = explode( ' ', $uptime[0] );

echo $uptime[0];//uptime in seconds
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your "method 1" does nothing. (well done editing before 5 mins) And your "method 2" doesn't answer the question. He wants the last boot time, not the current uptime.

Comment: In the first method, you can use `strtotime` to convert it to timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

```
who -b # in command-line
```

Gives you the last boot time (http://www.kernelhardware.org/find-last-reboot-time-and-date-on-linux/)

```
exec ( $command , $output ); // in PHP
```

Executes a shell command

```
strtotime(); // in PHP
```

Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

So this will give you the Linux System last boot time :

```
// in PHP
exec('who -b',$bootTime);//where $bootTime is an array, each line returned by the command is an element of the array
$result = strtotime($bootTime[1]);
```